# How to animate a kivy layout subclass?

Tags: python, animation, layout, kivy

I am subclassing `kivy.uix.layout`. The goal is to animate the child widgets by recalculating their position on each frame.

What’s the correct way of doing this?

I can schedule a re-layout by doing this:

```py
self.layout_clock = Clock.schedule_interval(self._trigger_layout, -1)
```

But I get lots of errors:

```
[CRITICAL] [Clock       ] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute
```

I guess by changing the childrens’ positions inside of `do_layout`, I trigger `do_layout` again by some event binding and thus create an infinite loop, right?

So how do I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "animate"? Can you give an example what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to move child widgets along a path. So the Layout needs to change the child wigdets’ positions over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I have found the solution myself. Kinda.

Referring to the chapter [Schedule before frame](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html#schedule-before-frame) in the docs, I thought a `timeout` of `-1` was what I needed as I wanted to first calculate all positions and then have the app draw all widgets there.

However, this does the above mentioned mess-up.
I don't quite understand why this is causing the described callback loop. If anybody likes to explain :-)

Anyway, what *does* work is a `timeout` of either `0`or `1/60` (for a framerate of 60).

```py
self.layout_clock = Clock.schedule_interval(self._trigger_layout, 0)
```

Now all my widgets move buttery smooth and there’s no more warnings.